# Splitting up a line integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x,y,z)=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ be a vector field and $\gamma$ some curve then the line integral can be written $\int_\gamma f_1dx+f_2dy+f_3dz$. I'm wondering when it is possible to split up the integral such that $\int_\gamma f_1dx+f_2dy+f_3dz=\int_\gamma f_1dx+\int_\gamma f_2dy+\int_\gamma f_3dz$.

For example $\int_\gamma x^2dx+y^2dy+z^2dz=\int_\gamma x^2dx+\int_\gamma y^2dy+\int_\gamma z^2dz$ or $\int_\gamma -ydx+xdy+(1+z^2)dz=\int_\gamma -ydx+xdy+\int_\gamma (1+z^2)dz$.

Comment: Always: why not? Follow the definition.

Comment: The problem I have is when a line integral is split to smaller line integrals it seems that one can always use potential functions to calculate the line integral. For example $\int_\gamma -ydx+xdy+(1+z^2)dz$ does not have a potential function but $\int_\gamma -ydx$, $\int_\gamma xdy$ and $\int_{\gamma }(1+z^2)dz$ each have one. So it makes any line integral trivial to calculate.

Comment: I cannot imagine why you cannot add the "potential functions to calculate the smaller line integrals" to make a "potential function for the big one". Can you please edit your post to include a concrete example, specifying not only these functions but also the curve $\gamma$?